# strange error with devise and unicorn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, unicorn

I used devise with many of my rails apps 
in development I am getting these error every day 1-2 times

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `users_url' for #<RegistrationsController:0x007f14cd6cd958>

          .0/gems/turbolinks-2.5.3/lib/turbolinks/
      xhr_headers.rb:  21:in `_compute_redirect_to_location'
     …0224210521/app/controllers/
        /home/remmon/apps/myapp/releases/20150224210521/app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
registrations_controller.rb:  26:in `create'
…le/ruby/2.1.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/
router.rb:  68:in `block in call'
…le/ruby/2.1.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/
router.rb:  56:in `each'
…le/ruby/2.1.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/
router.rb:  56:in `call'
…uby/2.1.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/
strategy.rb: 186:in `call!'
…uby/2.1.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/
strategy.rb: 164:in `call'
      …ems/rack-mobile-detect-0.4.0/lib/rack/
       mobile-detect.rb: 164:in `call'
      …dle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/
      manager.rb:  35:in `block in call'
      …dle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/
      manager.rb:  34:in `catch'
      …dle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/
      manager.rb:  34:in `call'
      …red/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/
       etag.rb:  23:in `call'
        …/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/
     conditionalget.rb:  35:in `call'
      …/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/
        id.rb: 210:in `context'
          …/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/
           id.rb: 205:in `call'
         …bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/
           sendfile.rb: 102:in `call'
           …/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/
              methodoverride.rb:  21:in `call'
             …/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/
           runtime.rb:  17:in `call'
       …red/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/
         lock.rb:  15:in `call'
           …by/2.1.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/
     context.rb: 136:in `forward'
      …by0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/
    context.rb: 143:in `pass'
…by/2.1.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/
context.rb: 155:in `invalidate'
…by/2.1.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/
context.rb:  71:in `call!'
…by/2.1.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/
context.rb:  51:in `call'
…undle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-cors-0.3.1/lib/rack/
cors.rb:  72:in `call'
…by/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/
http_server.rb: 576:in `process_client'
```

in unicorn.log I found these error

```
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
(facebook) Callback phase initiated.
```

, and the only solution is to

```
 sudo service unicorn_myapp stop
```

then starting it again with

```
 sudo service unicorn_myapp start
```

I checked my user model and related models for callbacks ,but everything is working fine , registration working very well after restarting unicorn as I said before

I am using ruby 2.1.5 and rails 3.2.21

here is my gem file too

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.21'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 3.12'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'pg'
gem 'thumbs_up'
gem "lol_dba"
gem "paperclip", "~> 3.5.1"
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'mobile-fu', '~> 1.3.1'
gem 'time_difference'
gem 'mongo_mapper'
gem 'bson_ext', "1.10.0"
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
gem 'humanizer'
gem 'birthday', '~> 0.3.0'
gem "embedly"
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
gem "aws-sdk"
gem 'zodiac'
#gem "searchkick"
gem "geocoder"
gem "strong_parameters"
gem 'redis-rails'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem "wysiwyg-rails"
gem "select2-rails"
gem 'mime-types', :require => 'mime/types'
#gem 'asset_sync' ,:git=>"git://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync.git"
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'turbo-sprockets-rails3'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development do

  gem 'thin'

  gem 'better_errors',"1.1.0"
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'meta_request'

  gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
end
gem 'ransack'

# gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
#gem 'mailboxer',:git=>"git://github.com/remon/mailboxer"
gem "mailboxer"
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-rails','2.1.4'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails','3.0.1'

#gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: '0-6-stable'
gem "devise"
gem 'cache_digests'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'
gem 'jquery-datatables-rails', '~> 2.2.1'
#gem "pjax_rails"
gem 'dalli'
gem 'simple_form'
gem "cocoon"
gem "squeel"
gem "kaminari" ,"0.14.1"
gem "jbuilder",'0.9.1'
# Use unicorn as the app server

# Deploy with Capistrano
group :production do

  gem 'unicorn'
end
#gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
#gem 'sidekiq',"2.17.7"
#gem "sidekiq", "3.3.0"
#gem 'capistrano-sidekiq', group: :development
gem 'daemons'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'sinatra', require: false
gem 'slim'
#gem 'capistrano-sidekiq', github: 'seuros/capistrano-sidekiq'
gem 'capistrano' ,"2.13.5"

#gem 'jquery-turbolinks'#
# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
```

her is my routes.rb

```
myApp::Application.routes.draw do



   namespace :api, defaults: { format: "json" } do
 devise_scope :user do
   post 'users' => 'registrations#create', :as => 'user_registration'
   post 'users/sign_in' => 'sessions#create', :as => 'user_session'
  get '/users/sign_out' => 'sessions#destroy'
    end

devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions=>"sessions", :registrations => "registrations", :passwords => "passwords" ,:omniauth_callbacks=>"omniauth_callbacks"}


##etc...
end
```

my registration controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_filter :prepare_for_mobile
  respond_to :js ,:html 

    def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
       #resource.skip_confirmation!
    resource_saved = resource.save
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_saved
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, location: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      @validatable = devise_mapping.validatable?
      if @validatable
        @minimum_password_length = resource_class.password_length.min
      end
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
   def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    resource_updated = update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
    yield resource if block_given?
    if resource_updated
      if is_flashing_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, bypass: true
      respond_with resource, location: after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
 step2_path
  end

end
```

also my rails traces error

```
…2.21/lib/action_dispatch/routing/
/home/remoncpo/apps/optlar/shared/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb
polymorphic_routes.rb: 129:in `polymorphic_url'
…tionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/routing/
url_for.rb: 150:in `url_for'
…pack-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
redirecting.rb: 105:in `_compute_redirect_to_location'
…pack-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
redirecting.rb:  74:in `redirect_to'
…actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
flash.rb:  25:in `redirect_to'
…-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
instrumentation.rb:  60:in `block in redirect_to'
…tivesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/
notifications.rb: 123:in `block in instrument'
….2.21/lib/active_support/notifications/
instrumenter.rb:  20:in `instrument'
…tivesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/
notifications.rb: 123:in `instrument'
…-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
instrumentation.rb:  59:in `redirect_to'
…onpack-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
responder.rb: 135:in `redirect_to'
…onpack-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
responder.rb: 193:in `navigation_behavior'
…onpack-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
responder.rb: 162:in `rescue in to_html'
…onpack-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
responder.rb: 160:in `to_html'
…onpack-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
responder.rb: 153:in `respond'
…onpack-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
responder.rb: 146:in `call'
…ck-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
mime_responds.rb: 239:in `respond_with'
…0228155747/app/controllers/
registrations_controller.rb:  26:in `create'
…-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
implicit_render.rb:   4:in `send_action'
…gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/abstract_controller/
base.rb: 167:in `process_action'
…onpack-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
rendering.rb:  10:in `process_action'
…actionpack-3.2.21/lib/abstract_controller/
callbacks.rb:  18:in `block in process_action'
…s/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/
callbacks.rb: 458:in `_run__2151305456332142610__process_action__86349116187657263__callbacks'
…s/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/
callbacks.rb: 405:in `__run_callback'
…s/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/
callbacks.rb: 385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
…s/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/
callbacks.rb:  81:in `run_callbacks'
…actionpack-3.2.21/lib/abstract_controller/
callbacks.rb:  17:in `process_action'
…ctionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
rescue.rb:  29:in `process_action'
…-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
instrumentation.rb:  30:in `block in process_action'
…tivesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/
notifications.rb: 123:in `block in instrument'
….2.21/lib/active_support/notifications/
instrumenter.rb:  20:in `instrument'
…tivesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/
notifications.rb: 123:in `instrument'
…-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
instrumentation.rb:  29:in `process_action'
…k-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
params_wrapper.rb: 207:in `process_action'
….2.21/lib/active_record/railties/
controller_runtime.rb:  18:in `process_action'
…gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/abstract_controller/
base.rb: 121:in `process'
…actionpack-3.2.21/lib/abstract_controller/
rendering.rb:  45:in `process'
…/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/
metal.rb: 203:in `dispatch'
…-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/metal/
rack_delegation.rb:  14:in `dispatch'
…/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_controller/
metal.rb: 246:in `block in action'
…onpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/routing/
route_set.rb:  73:in `call'
…onpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/routing/
route_set.rb:  73:in `dispatch'
…onpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/routing/
route_set.rb:  36:in `call'
…ctionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/routing/
mapper.rb:  43:in `call'
…le/ruby/2.1.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/
router.rb:  68:in `block in call'
…le/ruby/2.1.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/
router.rb:  56:in `each'
…le/ruby/2.1.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/
router.rb:  56:in `call'
…onpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/routing/
route_set.rb: 608:in `call'
…uby/2.1.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/
strategy.rb: 186:in `call!'
…uby/2.1.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/
strategy.rb: 164:in `call'
…ems/rack-mobile-detect-0.4.0/lib/rack/
mobile-detect.rb: 164:in `call'
…dle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/
manager.rb:  35:in `block in call'
…dle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/
manager.rb:  34:in `catch'
…dle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/
manager.rb:  34:in `call'
…b/action_dispatch/middleware/
best_standards_support.rb:  17:in `call'
…red/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/
etag.rb:  23:in `call'
…/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/
conditionalget.rb:  35:in `call'
…tionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/
head.rb:  14:in `call'
…3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/
params_parser.rb:  21:in `call'
…ionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/
flash.rb: 242:in `call'
…/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/
id.rb: 210:in `context'
…/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/session/abstract/
id.rb: 205:in `call'
…npack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/
cookies.rb: 341:in `call'
…s/activerecord-3.2.21/lib/active_record/
query_cache.rb:  64:in `call'
…record/connection_adapters/abstract/
connection_pool.rb: 479:in `call'
…ack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/
callbacks.rb:  28:in `block in call'
…s/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/
callbacks.rb: 405:in `_run__2996406385371488609__call__2187759682541233929__callbacks'
…s/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/
callbacks.rb: 405:in `__run_callback'
…s/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/
callbacks.rb: 385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
…s/activesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/
callbacks.rb:  81:in `run_callbacks'
…ack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/
callbacks.rb:  27:in `call'
…bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/
sendfile.rb: 102:in `call'
….21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/
debug_exceptions.rb:  16:in `call'
…2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/
show_exceptions.rb:  56:in `call'
…by/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/rack/
logger.rb:  32:in `call_app'
…by/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/rack/
logger.rb:  16:in `block in call'
…ivesupport-3.2.21/lib/active_support/
tagged_logging.rb:  22:in `tagged'
…by/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/rack/
logger.rb:  16:in `call'
…ck-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/
request_id.rb:  22:in `call'
…/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/
methodoverride.rb:  21:in `call'
…/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/
runtime.rb:  17:in `call'
….2.21/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/
local_cache.rb:  72:in `call'
…red/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/
lock.rb:  15:in `call'
…by/2.1.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/
context.rb: 136:in `forward'
…by/2.1.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/
context.rb: 143:in `pass'
…by/2.1.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/
context.rb: 155:in `invalidate'
…by/2.1.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/
context.rb:  71:in `call!'
…by/2.1.0/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/
context.rb:  51:in `call'
…undle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-cors-0.3.1/lib/rack/
cors.rb:  72:in `call'
…le/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/
engine.rb: 484:in `call'
…by/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/
application.rb: 231:in `call'
…gems/railties-3.2.21/lib/rails/railtie/
configurable.rb:  30:in `method_missing'
…by/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/
http_server.rb: 576:in `process_client'
…by/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/
http_server.rb: 670:in `worker_loop'
```

Comment: Can you show us your ``routes.rb`` regarding your ``users``? Do you have a ``users_url`` route? Did you customized your ``RegistrationsController``? Can you show it to us?

Comment: actually , the problem happens everyday at 2.05 am , all the day I have at least 200 new registrations and no problem

Comment: Interesting. But you fail to answer my questions ;)

Comment: Hmm reviewing the log, and considering the 2.05 am, it seems to be a problem of cache invalidation from ``rack-cache``. How did you configure that?

Comment: I added my registration controller too

Comment: how can I check for my rack-cache configuration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71923/discussion-between-dgilperez-and-remon-amin).

Comment: Can you please post the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: it not related to routes ,the problem happened everyday in the same time at 4.05 am , my unicorn instance stopped and I updated my question with unicorn.log

Comment: seems like it is turbolinks which is trying to do some fancy stuff which you have not taken into account. It tries to get your "/users" url, but you only have a POST action to users. Disabling turbolinks will probably solve your problem, but then it also will slow down load times and increase server load. On another note: If this is happening at the same time every day, then it might be someone scraping you website (could be google or someone else). Update your robots.txt if you want them to stop ;)

Comment: I removed turbolinks and I made many changes in omniauth-facebook gem still having the problem but with another error Geocoding API's response was not valid JSON.
Geocoding API's response was not valid JSON.
Geocoding API's response was not valid JSON.

Comment: @dgilperez kindly post the answer you told me in chatting ,however I didn't solve the problem yet ,but I want to give the points to you for helping me

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exact the error is, but by looking at the gem source code, `def polymorphic_url` method,

(`actionpack-4.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb`

```
# -- some code
inflection = if options[:action] && options[:action].to_s == "new"
          args.pop
          :singular
        elsif (record.respond_to?(:persisted?) && !record.persisted?)
          args.pop
          :plural
        elsif record.is_a?(Class)
          args.pop
          :plural
        else
          :singular
        end
```

it seems like, your `resource` object is become , either collection or `User.new`, then it becomes `:plural` and gives you that error. My guess is try to debug on that direction , HTH

Comment: but why the problem happens every day on the same time , I removed omniautable from devise and I implement facebook auth, with omniauth-facebook gem and yesterday in the same time I got (facebook) Authentication failure! no_authorization_code: OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook::NoAuthorizationCodeError, must pass either a
 `code` (via URL or by an `fbsr_XXX` signed request cookie)
in unicorn.log