# async factory in ionic sidemenu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I am using ionic framework for my mobile application 
what I need is when I click the side menu links I want the factory service to bring data from the server

what is happening now is only one http request sent to the server when the application run ,but when I click on any link in the side menu no requests sent

```
myapp.factory('Authy',function ($cookieStore,Auth,$http,$q) {

    return {
     can_go :function(){
               var deffered = $q.defer();
          $http.get(mainUrl+"/user_info.json")
                .success(function(data){
              deffered.resolve(data);
          }).error(function(){
             deffered.reject(); 
          });
             return deffered.promise;      
     }
    }


    });
```

in my controller

```
      myapp.controller("PowerCtrl",function($scope,Authy ,$cookieStore,$http ){
                  $scope.view_loading = true;
                   Authy.can_go().then(function(data){
     $scope.view_loading = false;
    if (data.user){
        var user = data.user;

        if ((user.country !="") && (user.city != "")) {
           $scope.coins = user.coins
              $scope.id =user.id
        $scope.current_vip =user.current_vip;
         $scope.vip_time =user.vip_time;


        }else{

         window.location.href="#/step2";     
        }
    }else{

     window.location.href="#/login";   
    }


 });

              });
```

my routers

```
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state("main",{
      url: "/",
      templateUrl: "templates/main.html",
      controller: "MainCtrl"
  })

  .state("login",{
      url: "/login",

      templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
      controller: "LoginCtrl"

  })
   .state("register",{
      url: "/register",

      templateUrl: "templates/register.html",
      controller: "RegisterCtrl"      
  })
 .state("step2",{
      url: "/step2",
      templateUrl: "templates/step2.html",
      controller: "StepCtrl"
  })


  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.home', {
    url: "/home",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
          controller: "HomeCtrl",

        templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.power', {
    url: "/power",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
          controller : "PowerCtrl",
        templateUrl: "templates/power.html"
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

Comment: Not the cause for your problem, but don't use the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572).

Comment: How I can solve these problem in your opinion ?

Comment: It should be `return { can_go: function(){ return $http.get(mainUrl+"/user_info.json"); } };`

Comment: and what about the controller , I need the view to wait till I get the data from the service

Comment: I didn't say anything about the controller. He just gets a promise from `can_go()` as always

Comment: I will try it and I will tell you how it worked with me

Comment: the same results ,when I navigate between side menu links only $http called first time ,but then nothing called and results not changed

Comment: Yes, as I told you, the deferred antipattern had nothing to do with the problem you're asking about.

Comment: so what is the solution now ?

Comment: i don't know, otherwise i would have posted an answer… But apparently controllers get instantiated only once, instead of every time you click a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to disable `caching` on the view, its enabled by default , Ex:

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="My Title!">
  ...
</ion-view>
```

read more about `caching` [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/)

Comment: you saved my day , thanks , you may also find a solution for one of biggest issue which I didn't find any solutions for it yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28730483/strange-error-with-devise-and-unicorn